# combining variables in a data.frame

Tags: r, sum, grouping

I have made the following xtable which has 11 factors for **Period** for Meso-American archaeological sites. I wish to combine some of the Periods as "CL" = "CL" + "EC" + "LC"   ALSO   "F" = "MF" + "LF"

I'd also like to recode the distance to represent (km) "0" = "0km" , "1" = "1-2 Km", "2"= "3-4km", "3 = 3-5km"

I only seem to be able to change the names, without keeping the data that goes with it in the Original table

Ideally it will look like This, but with fewer time Periods and the Distance properly shown. They are in Chronological order by time period, though only a few of them are shown here.

```
dput(bomxtab3)
structure(list(Period = structure(c(10L, 5L, 6L, 1L, NA, 8L, 
7L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 1L, NA, 8L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 
4L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 1L, NA, 8L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, NA, 8L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("EF", "MF", "LF", 
"TF", "CL", "EC", "LC", "ET", "LT", "AZ"), class = "factor"), 
    Distance = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    Population = c(242391L, 1774L, 1980L, 315L, 0L, 9898L, 1430L, 
    5355L, 5010L, 903L, 2420L, 83725L, 7953L, 3320L, 175L, 200L, 
    13514L, 2370L, 8943L, 15018L, 4909L, 17107L, 55994L, 5546L, 
    1105L, 0L, 0L, 16110L, 1405L, 4105L, 5905L, 335L, 21563L, 
    19636L, 4815L, 1670L, 0L, 0L, 12811L, 525L, 3950L, 8563L, 
    3845L, 8562L), `bomxtab2$Population/x` = c(0.603343903859653, 
    0.0883114297092792, 0.245201238390093, 0.642857142857143, 
    0, 0.189134962643074, 0.24956369982548, 0.239565159039055, 
    0.145234230055659, 0.0903722978382706, 0.0487392250060421, 
    0.208402821683352, 0.395908004778973, 0.411145510835913, 
    0.357142857142857, 1, 0.258230944146141, 0.413612565445026, 
    0.400080526103879, 0.435354823747681, 0.491293034427542, 
    0.344537984371224, 0.139376621049121, 0.276085225009956, 
    0.136842105263158, 0, 0, 0.307836355645577, 0.245200698080279, 
    0.183644253567754, 0.17117926716141, 0.0335268214571657, 
    0.434282606944333, 0.0488766534078746, 0.239695340501792, 
    0.206811145510836, 0, 0, 0.244797737565207, 0.0916230366492147, 
    0.176710061289312, 0.24823167903525, 0.384807846277022, 0.172440183678402
    )), row.names = c(NA, -44L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: Please include data using `dput` and show expected output. Read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to recode the variables you have. There is quite some information about that for example [here](https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/04/how-to-recode-a-column-with-dplyr-in-r/) and [here](https://aaroncharlton.com/2018/01/19/transforming-variables-with-dplyr/).
I am not quite sure I did it completely correct for the period variable, so that is why I created a new one. I use the `tidyverse` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% mutate(Period1 = case_when(
  Period %in% c("CL", "EC", "LC") ~ "CL",
  Period %in% c("MF","LF") ~ "F",
  TRUE ~ as.character(Period)) ,
  Distance1 = recode(Distance,
                     `0` = "0km",
                     `1` = "1-2km",
                     `2` = "2-3km",
                     `3` = "3-5km",)
  )
```

With the %>% you create a pipeline (which is from `dplyr`). The case when is used as an if statement, so if Xis true, do Y. Here I check whether some value from the column Period occurs in a vector, if true recode it.
Taking a random sample, it results in:

```
   Period Distance Population bomxtab2$Population/x Period1 Distance1
1      ET        0       9898            0.18913496      ET       0km
2      EF        3          0            0.00000000      EF     3-5km
3      ET        2      16110            0.30783636      ET     2-3km
4      MF        0        903            0.09037230       F       0km
5      ET        3      12811            0.24479774      ET     3-5km
6      MF        2        335            0.03352682       F     2-3km
7      LC        2       1405            0.24520070      CL     2-3km
8      TF        3       8562            0.17244018      TF     3-5km
9      CL        0       1774            0.08831143      CL       0km
10     ET        1      13514            0.25823094      ET     1-2km
```